# How can I create vertical lines indentation in algorithm pseudo code correctly without end keywords?

Tags: algorithms

I found this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144840/vertical-loop-block-lines-in-algorithmicx-with-noend-option) and I applied it but this is the result.

[image]

This is my code.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\PassOptionsToPackage{noend}{algpseudocode}% comment out if want end's to show
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
% start with some helper code
% This is the vertical rule that is inserted
\newcommand*{\algrule}[1][\algorithmicindent]{\makebox[#1][l]{\hspace*{.5em}\vrule height .75\baselineskip depth .25\baselineskip}}%

\newcount\ALG@printindent@tempcnta
\def\ALG@printindent{%
    \ifnum \theALG@nested>0% is there anything to print
    \ifx\ALG@text\ALG@x@notext% is this an end group without any text?
    % do nothing
    \addvspace{-3pt}% FUDGE for cases where no text is shown, to make the rules line up
    \else
    \unskip
    % draw a rule for each indent level
    \ALG@printindent@tempcnta=1
    \loop
    \algrule[\csname ALG@ind@\the\ALG@printindent@tempcnta\endcsname]%
    \advance \ALG@printindent@tempcnta 1
    \ifnum \ALG@printindent@tempcnta<\numexpr\theALG@nested+1\relax% can't do <=, so add one to RHS and use < instead
    \repeat
    \fi
    \fi
}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
% the following line injects our new indent handling code in place of the default spacing
\patchcmd{\ALG@doentity}{\noindent\hskip\ALG@tlm}{\ALG@printindent}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
\makeatother
% end vertical rule patch for algorithmicx
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Arbitrary Algorithm}\label{IS2OSLS}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \Require A matrix $\mathbf{A}$ of size $m\times n$.
            \Ensure Something.
            \For{$i$ in $m$}
                \For{$j$ in $n$}
                    \If{$i=j$}
                        \State Select a random action
                    \Else
                        \If{$i=j+1$}
                            \State Stay silent 
                        \Else 
                            \State Break
                        \EndIf
                    \EndIf
                \EndFor
            \EndFor
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

I wold like to have vertical lines that start just after the first letter of the keyword, i.e., for the keyword `for` the vertical line should start after `f`, etc. In the figure above, the vertical lines start after the `o` not the `f`. Also I need the pseudo code without the `end` keyword as shown.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I can change `\hspace*{.5em}` to `\hspace*{.1em}` in order to move the vertical line a little to the left. This is solved. But why do the lines overlaps at the end of the algorithm? (If I add the `end` keywords the problem is solved.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An `\addvspace` instruction that is the cause for overlapping; remove it. I also added another patch that avoids spurious vertical space when an “end” tag is omitted, see [Spurious whitespace with algpseudocode and noend](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290445/spurious-whitespace-with-algpseudocode-and-noend)

For moving left the rules, act on the `\hspace{.5em}`, as you discovered; in the example I used `.2em`.

In the following code I left only the necessary packages.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% start with some helper code
% This is the vertical rule that is inserted
\newcommand*{\algrule}[1][\algorithmicindent]{%
  \makebox[#1][l]{%
    \hspace*{.2em}% <------------- This is where the rule starts from
    \vrule height .75\baselineskip depth .25\baselineskip
  }
}

\newcount\ALG@printindent@tempcnta
\def\ALG@printindent{%
    \ifnum \theALG@nested>0% is there anything to print
    \ifx\ALG@text\ALG@x@notext% is this an end group without any text?
    % do nothing
    \else
    \unskip
    % draw a rule for each indent level
    \ALG@printindent@tempcnta=1
    \loop
    \algrule[\csname ALG@ind@\the\ALG@printindent@tempcnta\endcsname]%
    \advance \ALG@printindent@tempcnta 1
    \ifnum \ALG@printindent@tempcnta<\numexpr\theALG@nested+1\relax
    \repeat
    \fi
    \fi
}
% the following line injects our new indent handling code in place of the default spacing
\patchcmd{\ALG@doentity}{\noindent\hskip\ALG@tlm}{\ALG@printindent}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
\patchcmd{\ALG@doentity}{\item[]\nointerlineskip}{}{}{} % no spurious vertical space
% end vertical rule patch for algorithmicx
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Arbitrary Algorithm}\label{IS2OSLS}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Require A matrix $\mathbf{A}$ of size $m\times n$.
  \Ensure Something.
  \For{$i$ in $m$}
    \For{$j$ in $n$}
      \If{$i=j$}
        \State Select a random action
      \Else
        \If{$i=j+1$}
          \State Stay silent 
        \Else 
          \State Break
        \EndIf
      \EndIf
    \EndFor
  \EndFor
\end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there an easy way to change the color of the vertical lines (like, gray more transparent)? For example, this color #c2c2c2 Color Hex Gray76.

Comment: @Chiba Yes, of course: add `\color{whatever}` just before `\vrule`.

Comment: For some reason, the vertical rules are sometimes dashed like
|
|
| (in vertical fashion). 
I mean there is a little space like every 1 cm. What would I get this?

Comment: @Chiba I suspect you're using `setspace`

Comment: I am not using `setspace` package. But, when I remove this line `\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}`, there is no spaces and the vertical rules are fine. Do you know how can I fix this?

Comment: @Chiba Sorry, but if I add that call to the code above, I get solid rules. Please, ask a new question with a minimal example showing the issue.

Comment: I asked a new question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301462/why-are-vertical-rules-dashed-sometimes-with-algorithmc-package)

Comment: Nice, but it does not work when using `\usepackage{algpseudocode}` one has to use `\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}` which makes the algorithm not look as good since missing all the `end if` and other `end`. It will be great if this worked with `end` support.

Comment: fyi, I am OK now. Found another solution which worked without using `noend`. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52473/is-it-possible-to-have-connecting-loop-lines-like-algorithm2e-in-algorithmic  . Thanks.