# Why are vertical rules dashed sometimes with algorithmic package?

Tags: algorithmicx, algorithmic

I would like to create vertical rules for indentation with algorithmic package. I applied the solution proposed here [How can I create vertical lines indentation in algorithm pseudo code correctly without end keywords?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292815/how-can-i-create-vertical-lines-indentation-in-algorithm-pseudo-code-correctly-w)

However, when I applied this solution I get dashed vertical lines as follows:

[image]
and the amount of dashes increase as the code increase.

My LaTeX code is the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,journal,compsoc,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
% start with some helper code
% This is the vertical rule that is inserted
\newcommand*{\algrule}[1][\algorithmicindent]{%
    \makebox[#1][l]{%
        \hspace*{.2em}% <------------- This is where the rule starts from
        \vrule height .75\baselineskip depth .25\baselineskip
    }
}

\newcount\ALG@printindent@tempcnta
\def\ALG@printindent{%
    \ifnum \theALG@nested>0% is there anything to print
    \ifx\ALG@text\ALG@x@notext% is this an end group without any text?
    % do nothing
    \else
    \unskip
    % draw a rule for each indent level
    \ALG@printindent@tempcnta=1
    \loop
    \algrule[\csname ALG@ind@\the\ALG@printindent@tempcnta\endcsname]%
    \advance \ALG@printindent@tempcnta 1
    \ifnum \ALG@printindent@tempcnta<\numexpr\theALG@nested+1\relax
    \repeat
    \fi
    \fi
}
% the following line injects our new indent handling code in place of the default spacing
\patchcmd{\ALG@doentity}{\noindent\hskip\ALG@tlm}{\ALG@printindent}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
\patchcmd{\ALG@doentity}{\item[]\nointerlineskip}{}{}{} % no spurious vertical space
% end vertical rule patch for algorithmicx
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Arbitrary Algorithm}\label{IS}

    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Require A matrix $\mathbf{A}$ of size $m\times n$.
        \Ensure Something.
        \For{$i$ in $m$}
            \For{$j$ in $n$}
                \If{$i=j$}
                    \State Select a random action
                \Else
                \If{$i=j+1$}
                    \State Stay silent 
                \Else 
                    \State Break
                \EndIf
                \EndIf
            \EndFor
        \EndFor
    \end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}



\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{\textsc{Increase Algorithm}}
    \label{algo:ffig}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Require{$T$.}
        \Ensure{A pair.}

        \For{$\ell\gets1$ \textbf{to} $L$}
            \For{$t\gets1$ \textbf{to} $T$}     
                \State $x_\ell^t\gets 0$
            \EndFor
        \EndFor         
        \For{$\ell\gets 1$ \textbf{to} $L$}
            \For{$t\gets1$ \textbf{to} $T$}
                \State $x_\ell^t\gets 1$
                \State $S_\ell^t\gets 0$
                \For{$\ell'\gets1$ \textbf{to} $L$}
                    \State $S_\ell^t\gets S_\ell^t + t$
                \EndFor

            \EndFor
        \EndFor
        \State \Return The solution
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in two consecutive lines having high and deep symbols.

You can cure it by using a slightly larger depth of the rule:

```
\newcommand*{\algrule}[1][\algorithmicindent]{%
    \makebox[#1][l]{%
        \hspace*{.2em}% <------------- This is where the rule starts from
        \vrule height .75\baselineskip depth .3\baselineskip
    }
}
```

In the example I did `\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}` instead of loading `mtpro2`: Times math fonts don't go along with the Palatino font used by the class, but the result is the same with `mtpro2`.

[image]