# Vertical line and numerating problems when using algorithm package to split an algorithm with long texts

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx, algorithmic

I am making a two parts splited algorithm with vertical lines and numbering. I prefer to use **`algorithm`** package rather than using **`algorithm2e`** package, because this one does not provid either `\algstore` and `\algrestore` command pair or some easy solution about vertical lines and numerating, when algorithm is broken in two parts. Because of that, based on solution of issue "[How can I create vertical lines indentation in algorithm pseudo code correctly without end keywords?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292838/155670)", I am breaking this algorithm in two parts, using those **`algorithm`** command pair. It is working fine, according this figure:

[image]

But, when I use a long text, two problems (red lines) are appearing:

1. The long text exceds left margin, which is interrupting the three vertical lines continuation, according to one sees at line 4;
2. Breaking of vertical alignment from line that is below of both second **for** and first **if**, according to lines 2 and 3 (compare with lines 1 and 6), respectively.

Therfore, I would like to achieve the follow solutions:

1. Compress the width of long text in justify alignment, without both interrupting the vertical lines;
2. Correct the vertical alignment errors of lines that are starting below of both second **for** and first **if** (blue lines for both **for** and **if** references).

So, how can I do that?

Here, I put the figure MWE code.

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\makeatletter
% start with some helper code
% This is the vertical rule that is inserted
\newcommand*{\algrule}[1][\algorithmicindent]{%
  \makebox[#1][l]{%
    \hspace*{.2em}% <------------- This is where the rule starts from
    \vrule height .75\baselineskip depth .25\baselineskip
  }
}

\newcount\ALG@printindent@tempcnta
\def\ALG@printindent{%
    \ifnum \theALG@nested>0% is there anything to print
    \ifx\ALG@text\ALG@x@notext% is this an end group without any text?
    % do nothing
    \else
    \unskip
    % draw a rule for each indent level
    \ALG@printindent@tempcnta=1
    \loop
    \algrule[\csname ALG@ind@\the\ALG@printindent@tempcnta\endcsname]%
    \advance \ALG@printindent@tempcnta 1
    \ifnum \ALG@printindent@tempcnta<\numexpr\theALG@nested+1\relax
    \repeat
    \fi
    \fi
}
% the following line injects our new indent handling code in place of the default spacing
\patchcmd{\ALG@doentity}{\noindent\hskip\ALG@tlm}{\ALG@printindent}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
\patchcmd{\ALG@doentity}{\item[]\nointerlineskip}{}{}{} % no spurious vertical space
% end vertical rule patch for algorithmicx
\makeatother

\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Input:}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicensure{\textbf{Output:}}



\begin{document}


% ---> Algorithm 01.

\begin{algorithm}

\caption{Arbitrary Algorithm}\label{IS2OSLS}

    \begin{algorithmic}[1]

        \Require A matrix $\mathbf{A}$ of size $m\times n$.
        \Ensure Something.  

        \For{$i$ in $m$}
            \For{$j$ in $n$}
                \If{$i=j$}
                    \State Select a random action. \lipsum[1]
                \Else
                    \If{$i=j+1$}
                        \State Stay silent 
                    \Else 
                        \State Break
        \algstore{bkbreak}

    \end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}

% ---> Algorithm 01: continuation.

\begin{algorithm}

    \begin{algorithmic}

        \algrestore{bkbreak}

                    \EndIf
                \EndIf
            \EndFor
        \EndFor

    \end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following updates the answer in [How can I create vertical lines indentation in algorithm pseudo code correctly without end keywords?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292838/5764). Here are the key elements:

- Use a `\StatePar` to enter a `\State` paragraph. This adds a `\strut` and the start and end of the paragraph to allow for proper baseline skip.
- The `algorithmic` environment has been updated to start with `\offinterlineskip`. This removes the gap between each statement that is usually present in the vertical rules.
- All keywords and the `\State` command have been updated to use a `\strut` to allow for a better presentation with vertical spacing (also due to `\offinterlineskip`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
% start with some helper code
% This is the vertical rule that is inserted
\newcommand*{\algrule}[1][\algorithmicindent]{%
  \hspace*{.2em}% <------------- This is where the rule starts from
  \vrule %height .75\baselineskip depth .25\baselineskip
  \hspace*{\dimexpr#1-.2em-.4pt}%
}

\newcommand{\StatePar}[1]{%
  \State\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\ALG@thistlm}{\strut #1\strut}%
}
\renewcommand{\ALG@beginalgorithmic}{\offinterlineskip}% Remove all interline skips

\newcount\ALG@printindent@tempcnta
\def\ALG@printindent{%
  \ifnum \theALG@nested > 0% is there anything to print
    \ifx\ALG@text\ALG@x@notext% is this an end group without any text?
      % do nothing
    \else
      \unskip
      % draw a rule for each indent level
      \ALG@printindent@tempcnta=1
      \loop
        \algrule[\csname ALG@ind@\the\ALG@printindent@tempcnta\endcsname]%
        \advance \ALG@printindent@tempcnta 1
        \ifnum \ALG@printindent@tempcnta<\numexpr\theALG@nested+1\relax
      \repeat
        \fi
    \fi
}
% the following line injects our new indent handling code in place of the default spacing
\patchcmd{\ALG@doentity}{\noindent\hskip\ALG@tlm}{\ALG@printindent}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
% end vertical rule patch for algorithmicx
\makeatother

% Add \struts to keywords
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicend{\strut\textbf{end}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicdo{\strut\textbf{do}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicwhile{\strut\textbf{while}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicfor{\strut\textbf{for}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicforall{\strut\textbf{for all}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicloop{\strut\textbf{loop}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrepeat{\strut\textbf{repeat}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicuntil{\strut\textbf{until}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicprocedure{\strut\textbf{procedure}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicfunction{\strut\textbf{function}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicif{\strut\textbf{if}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicthen{\strut\textbf{then}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicelse{\strut\textbf{else}}

\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\strut\textbf{Input:}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicensure{\strut\textbf{Output:}}

\let\oldState\State
\renewcommand{\State}{\oldState\strut}

\begin{document}

% ---> Algorithm 01.
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Arbitrary Algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Require A matrix $\mathbf{A}$ of size $m\times n$.
    \Ensure Something.  
    \For{$i$ in $m$}
      \For{$j$ in $n$}
        \If{$i = j$}
          \StatePar{Select a random action. \lipsum[1]}
        \Else
          \If{$i = j + 1$}
            \State Stay silent 
          \Else 
            \State Break
            \algstore{bkbreak}
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

% ---> Algorithm 01: continuation.
\begin{algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}
            \algrestore{bkbreak}
          \EndIf
        \EndIf
      \EndFor
    \EndFor
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what I am wanting. Thank you by help. But I have a question: what do `\strut` and `\showoutput` commands do? I also tested this improvement with another tex code. I noted that there are some short interruptions among vertical lines, whenever it did transiction between any command statement (for instance `\If`, `\Repeat`, `\ForAll` among others) and `\StatePar` command statement. But, either among the own `\StatePar` command statements or from `\StatePar` to another command statement, there are no short interruptions. What could it be happening?

Comment: Those short interruptions are as in the issue [Why are vertical rules dashed sometimes with algorithmic package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/301462/155670). But in your solution, I noted that you did a short adjust in \vrule command. Does it influence in those short interruptions?

Comment: @Adriano: `\showoutput` was left over from debugging. I've removed it. Can you provide a minimal example showing some of you remaining issues? You can put the code on [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) if you wish.

Comment: I made a MWE with those problems using the same code example, according to your suggestion. This is avaliable in Pastebin, through of issue [LaTeX MWE refering to vertical line on algorithm package](https://pastebin.com/z4CGYASY). I am using LaTeX elsarticle class, because those problems are appearing in Elsevier article mask. This is avaliable in [Elsevier LaTeX instructions](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions). It seems that problems are in mathematical symbol sizes, because short interruptions are noted in the lines that appear.

Comment: @Adriano: I've updated the answer to correct the issue. It now sets `\offinterlineskip` as part of `\ALG@beginalgorithmic`, so there's no more need for `\vspace{-\lineskip}` as part of `\StatePar`.

Comment: I have put the command line `\renewcommand{\ALG@beginalgorithmic}{\offinterlineskip}% Remove all interline skips`, and I also have taken `\vspace{-lineskip}` out of `\StatePar` statement, according to your correction. As a consequence, your algorithm package patch is perfectly working right now, as way as I am wanting. Thank you by help.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed comment. I am trying to find a way to reduce the vertical space between lines inside the par box but without success. Is that possible? Could you please suggest a way?

Comment: @Darkmoor: Are you using something currently that spreads it out? Like [`setspace`](//ctan.org/pkg/setspace)?

Comment: @Werner Thanks for your comment, no I don't use something that spreads out. The space between lines is the default as the one in your post. I just want to reduce it.

Comment: @Darkmoor: Read this: [Why is the linespread factor as it is?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30073/5764) You can adjust `\linespread`, or use [`setspace`](//ctan.org/pkg/setspace) with a small adjustment to condense the text.