# How to reproduce this pseudocode?

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx, algorithmic, pseudocode, algpseudocode

I am trying to replicate the style of the following pseudocode.
[image: Original pseudocode]

The following minimal working example almost produces what I want except the extra vertical space between lines 7 and 8. How can I resolve this issue? Is there an easier way to format pseudocodes this way?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newcommand{\Def}[3]{\textbf{#1}\ \textsc{#2}\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{(#3)}}
\algrenewcommand{\alglinenumber}[1]{\footnotesize#1\hspace{1em}}% <- This line

\begin{document}

    \Def{procedure}{Euclidian}{$a,b$}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State $x \gets a$
        \State $y \gets b$
        \While{$x \not= y$}
            \If{$x < y$}
                \State $x \gets x - y$
            \Else
                \State $y \gets y - x$
            \EndIf
        \EndWhile
        \State \textbf{return} $x$
    \end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**
I have tried clrscode3e this time. It worked, but required me to *hack* the package code. I still wonder if there is an easier solution.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{clrscode3e}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

% Restore \gets
\let\gets=\leftarrow

% Print 'do' and 'then'
\renewcommand{\Do}{\textbf{do}\addtocounter{indent}{1}}
\renewcommand{\Then}{\textbf{then}\addtocounter{indent}{1}}

% Indent recursively (\hspace is used instead of \>)
\renewcommand{\putindents}{\ifnum\value{thisindent}>0%
    \hspace{1.5em}\addtocounter{thisindent}{-1}\putindents%
\fi}

% Line number separation (hspace is added)
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\liprint}{\protected@xdef\@lilabel{\thecodelinenumber}%
    \ifnumberedline\thecodelinenumber\fi\'\hspace{0.25em}\Indent%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{codebox}
    \Procname{\textbf{procedure} $\proc{Euclidian}(a,b)$}
    \li $x \gets a$
    \li $y \gets b$
    \li \While $x \not= y$ \Do
    \li     \If $x < y$ \Then
    \li         $x \gets x - y$
    \li     \Else
    \li         $y \gets y - x$
            \End
        \End
    \li \Return $x$
    \end{codebox}   

\end{document}
```

**Edit 2**
The patch proposed by @egreg fixes vertical alignment, but I have one more issue. In the first MWE, *the marked line* left-aligns the line numbers by increasing the separation. However, it cannot handle multidigit line numbers. What are your suggestions?

Comment: Looks like `noend` is the culprit

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: If I apply the patch suggested in the answer to the duplicate question, I get [this result (click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kMLf.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [Spurious whitespace with `algpseudocode` and `noend`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290454/5764) corrects the vertical alignment, the horizontal alignment of the line numbering can be changed using a fixed-width box:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ALG@doentity}{\item[]\nointerlineskip}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\Def}[3]{\textbf{#1}\ \textsc{#2}\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{(#3)}}
\algrenewcommand{\alglinenumber}[1]{\makebox[1.5em][l]{\footnotesize#1}}
\algrenewcommand{\Return}[1]{\State \textbf{return} #1}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@procedure}[1][\relax]{%
  \def\procedurearg{#1}%
  \textbf{procedure}
  \textsc{\procedurename}%
  \ifx\procedurearg\relax\else
    (#1)%
  \fi
  \par
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
}
\newenvironment{procedure}[1]
  {\par
   \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Remove paragraph indent
   \def\procedurename{#1}%
   \@procedure
  }
  {\end{algorithmic}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{procedure}{Euclidian}[$a,b$]
  \State $x \gets a$
  \State $y \gets b$
  \While{$x \not= y$}
    \If{$x < y$}
      \State $x \gets x - y$
    \Else
      \State $y \gets y - x$
    \EndIf
  \EndWhile
  \Return{$x$}
\end{procedure}

\end{document}
```

For convenience, I've wrapped the procedure-`algorithmic` mix into a single `procedure` environment.

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly is the problem you are trying to solve. The horizontal alignment in the linked solution to the linked question seems to be fine. I do not understand which aspect of horizontal alignment are you referring to here. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @Krishna: [This is the original problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8dbQ.png) the OP wanted fixed; the [linked duplicate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290454/5764) fixes that. However, the OP used an odd redefinition for `\alglinenumber`. The issue is only realised when you have more than 9 numbered lines, like in [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXYM5.png). I used a fixed-width box redefinition instead which [corrects this behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDaSD.png).